# How to transform a multidimensional array to JSON in classic ASP?

Tags: json, asp-classic

I have this code in Classical ASP:

```
    dim arr(2,3)
arr(0,0) = "proc"
arr(1,0) = "code"
arr(2,0) = "hour"

arr(0,1) = "11111"
arr(1,1) = "01"
arr(2,1) = "5"

arr(0,2) = "22222"
arr(1,2) = "02"
arr(2,2) = "6"

arr(0,3) = "33333"
arr(1,3) = "03"
arr(2,3) = "4"
```

and I'd like to transform in a JSON like below in Classical ASP too:

```
{"process":[
                {"proc" : "11111", "code" : "01", "hour":"5"},
                {"proc" : "22222", "code" : "02", "hour":"6"},
                {"proc" : "33333", "code" : "03", "hour":"4"}
               ]
    }
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function that will perform the serialization to json for the type record array you are using:

```
Function RecordArrayToJSON(arr)

    ReDim arrObj(UBound(arr, 2) - 1)

    Dim i, j
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        ReDim arrProp(UBound(arr, 1))
        For j = 0 To UBound(arr, 1)
            arrProp(j) = """" & arr(j, 0) & """ : """ & arr(j, i) & """"
        Next 

        arrObj(i-1) = "{" & Join(arrProp, ", ") & "}"
    Next

    RecordArrayToJSON = "[" + Join(arrObj, ",") + "]"
End Function
```

You get your final JSON with:

```
 Dim json : json = "{""process"":" + RecordArrayToJSON(arr) + "}"
```

There is the assumption that all property values are strings which is the case in your example.